# Where can I QuickForm2 documentation

Tags: documentation, pear, quickform

I spent the past few hours searching for a tutorial/documentation for QuickForm2 but seems like there is no such thing other than the examples attached with the package itself which are not sufficient at all. I tried looking through the API documentation but I can't find a method called addElement for example which is the most used method there. I just need any good tutorial about the second version of the package or would you please tell me where can i find the methods (addElement, addRule, element specific methods like setValue, setOptions, setContent ... etc).

Answer (score 2):

There is a bunch of examples here (on Ubuntu):

```
/usr/share/doc/php5-common/PEAR/HTML_QuickForm2/examples/
```

If you are on another distro you can do:

```
locate QuickForm2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with QuickForm, but a google search found this page:

[http://pear.php.net/reference/HTML_QuickForm2-latest/li_HTML_QuickForm2.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120502210345/http://pear.php.net/reference/HTML_QuickForm2-latest/li_HTML_QuickForm2.html)

I think you're possibly struggling because the methods you're looking for are in the base classes.

For example:

[`Element`](https://web.archive.org/web/20110211220237/http://pear.php.net:80/reference/HTML_QuickForm2-latest/HTML_QuickForm2/_HTML_QuickForm2-0.3.0---QuickForm2---Element.php.html) mentions that it Includes `Node.php`.

[`Node`](https://web.archive.org/web/20111229180146/http://pear.php.net:80/reference/HTML_QuickForm2-latest/HTML_QuickForm2/HTML_QuickForm2_Node.html) has an `addRule` method (and a `setValue` one).

`addElement` looks like its in the [`Container`](https://web.archive.org/web/20120502080517/http://pear.php.net:80/reference/HTML_QuickForm2-latest/HTML_QuickForm2/HTML_QuickForm2_Container.html#methodaddElement) class

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [HTML_QuickForm2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2) is in the PEAR manual: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform2.php

`addElement` is in `HTML/QuickForm2/Container.php`.